# Guam - Revenge of the Birds

Tags: science-based, biology, ecology

To quickly recap how Guam became eerily devoid of chirping sounds, it is supposed that an invasive species of snake hitched its way to the island on a cargo ship and began multiplying and exploiting the vacuum in the food chain -- no natural predators and a buffet of prey.

Some birds have gone totally extinct, but in my world a few have had their DNA/embryos stored offshore ready to be reintroduced when conditions seem appropriate.

But for the birds of Guam to make a glorious comeback, some other animal(s) will need to take out the snakes. But they themselves could wind up being obstacles. Scientists have notoriously gotten it wrong when it comes to the nuanced procedure of altering a biome. [The introduction of toads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cane_toads_in_Australia#Introduction_and_spread) to Australia to address a beetle issue merely resulted in toads running amok. These toads reportedly even ate small mammals, becoming a bigger problem than the original beetle problem.

This brings us to the question. I'm trying to devise a setting where the birds of Guam can be safely reintroduced from offshore. Deceptively simple, as other scientists have painfully discovered for themselves.

[image]

### Question

What pre-meditated biome-altering tools/approaches (sequence of animal releases for simplicity's sake) have a scientific basis for working?

**Quality metric:** Prefer less collateral damage: more scalpel less sledgehammer.

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having with the solution you already have? What do we need to fix here? It would be a good idea to [post this question in the sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) until you have it formatted well for the site. It is likely to be closed as "needing more details" in the mean time, and can be opened up again when the problem is well scoped.

Comment: What have the snakes been eating since they wiped out the birds? If their numbers exceed their food supply then the snakes will die of starvation. For that matter, what sort of snake invaded in the first place?

Comment: Edited for clarity. Still fairly straight forward, there is a history to consider about failed attempts -- with that in mind, what is a reasonable science-based alternative to achieve balance in the ecosystem (for the birds)

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post. Relative quality metrics don't restrict the scope of what answers are valid. Try reframing the question so that answers can be evaluated individually for quality, instead of only being evaluated relative to each other

Comment: @sphennings Fair enough, edited to 1 question.

Comment: You're still asking an open ended question with many valid answers. Such questions aren't a good fit on this site either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Sterile Snakes

Release snakes that have been genetically modified to produce sterile offspring and a shorter life. Do this across the course of a decade or so and you'll have a generation of snakes who can't have babies, wiping them out. [This has already been done to help fight disease carrying mosquitoes](https://www.palmbeachpost.com/story/news/columns/2022/03/16/epa-tries-sterile-genetically-modified-male-mosquitoes-florida-keys-zika-virus/7047370001/).

Answer (score 6):

**Fight fire with fire.**

You will release tens of thousands of captive reared brown tree snakes liberally across the island all at once.  This will be followed the next year by another release of thousands of snakes, and again the year after that.

Then you will wait a few years.  Everything that can be eaten by a snake will have been wiped out by the snake tsunami.  Nothing native to Guam eats these snakes so no population will boom on the ample snakes.  With no birds or small animals left, snakes will get hungry.  Big snakes will eat little snakes.  Then the snakes will die of starvation.  There will be no snakes and no birds.

Then you will reintroduce the birds.   If there is one huge snake left because it has sustained itself on all the rest, it can live in a zoo and dream about the glory days.

Comment: I suspect the complete destruction of every small animal on Guam might constitute excessive collateral damage..

Comment: @Ruadhan - consider it a sort of catharsis.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the size of your snakes. If they were small ones just release chickens. They will eat the snake young and kill the adults. Chickens are nasty birds. I have some at home allowed to roam freely inside and outside because they kill and eat the big poisonous centipedes here. They're great for pest control.

The other thing about chickens is what to do with them when their mission is accomplished. Humans know exactly what to do with chickens, we eat them, the more the merrier.

Comment: Poetic justice in that Chickens are birds

Comment: The snakes are between 1 and 3 meters long and frequently climb trees. They're also venomous constrictors. In Guam, they've been responsible for killing a lot of family pets (cats and small dogs presumably) I suspect chickens may simply be additional prey.

Comment: @Ruadhan from what I read they're 2 -3 feet long and chickens are hard to bite. Our centipedes aren't that big but their venom puts me in a bunch of pain for days, never seen them manage to hurt a chicken.

Comment: @Kilisi "Owing to the availability of prey and lack of predators in introduced habitats such as Guam, they have been known to grow to larger sizes than their normal 1 to 2 m (3.3 to 6.6 ft) in length. The longest recorded length of this species is one found on Guam measuring 3 m (9.8 ft)." - per the wikipedia article on Brown Tree Snakes

Answer (score 1):

**No food, snakes will die out**

Snake can't hunt fish. After the extinction of the birds what's left to eat? There will be some small insects. But also their numbers will dwindle and they won't provide a lot of energy to the snakes. Will they try eating crabs? Can they puncture the carapace with their teeth? How can they digest the carapace then? They don't munch, they swallow their preys whole.

There are not many islands colonised by snakes and for a good reason.